# Collecting data from a strongly typed razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

It's my first asp.net mvc application at all. I'm using mvc 3 and razor for my views. The specific view with which I have problem is a strongly-typed view (at least I think it is) but it accepts type of this kind :

```
@model List<List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>[]>
```

I made several partial view because the main view was very customized and I need a lot of different logic for different parts of my data. My partial view are also strongly typed (again I think this is correct to say) of type :

```
@model List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>[]
```

Everything that I need to build my view is in :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethodName", "Forms", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="drawForm">
        <table border="1">
```

Inside `Hhtml.BeginForm` I build table with all the data that comes from the controller. Now on submit :

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

I'm looking for the best way to get my data, and update in the database what is changed. In my controller I have this method :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ActionMethodName(FormCollection collection)
        {
            var test = collection;
            List<MCS_Documents> model = DocumentsService.All().ToList();
            return View("Index", model);
        }
```

This way I can find my data, but it's so complicated, I'm not even sure how I'll get to it. I tried something else, using the same method but accepting as argument the type which the view accepts :

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ActionMethodName(List<List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>[]> collection)
            {
```

But when I do that collections has null value. And from the little I know when I use strongly-typed view I can get some additional advantages like form.validation and data binding ready for update and so on...

So what is the best way, in my specific scenario, to deal with the data submitted from the form?

P.S

This is how I render my main view :

```
<table border="1">
            <colgroup>
            <col span="1" style="width: 10%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 40%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 25%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 25%;" />
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (Model[i][0][0].ContentTypeId == 1)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_PartialHeader", Model[i])
                    }
                    else if (Model[i][0][0].ContentTypeId == 2)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_PartialDrawing", Model[i])
                    }
                    else if (Model[i][0][0].ContentTypeId == 3)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_PartialBody", Model[i])
                    }
                    else if (Model[i][0][0].ContentTypeId == 4)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_PartialFooter", Model[i])
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
```

and this is one of my partials, just to showcase how I use them :

```
@model List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>[] 
        <tr>          
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model[0][0].FieldValue))
                { 
                    <td colspan="2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[0][0].FieldValue)
                    </td>
                }
                else
                { 
                    <td colspan="2">
                    Sign in here
                    </td>
                }         

                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model[1][0].FieldValue))
                { 
                    <td colspan="2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[1][0].FieldValue)
                    </td>
                }
                else
                { 
                    <td colspan="2">
                    Sign in here
                    </td>
                }        

        </tr>
```

Comment: Please show how you render data from your model (There must be some kind of loop somewhere)

Comment: @Jan Please see the edited original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That last action method is correct (which takes your strong type), but your views will need to be structured differently. You need to make sure that **every** collection (even the sub collections) are correctly indexed, **otherwise model binding will fail**.

Your views should be something like the following (note the use of `for` loops):

Main view:

```
@model List<List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>[]>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.RenderPartial("PartialName", Model[i])
}
```

Then in your Partial:

```
  @model List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>[]

  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
      //Not sure if you need anything at this level
      for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Count(); j++)
      {
          //Add your EditorFor's, HiddenFor's etc for the child type
      }
  }
```

Comment: Wow, you haven't even see my update. You can see the code that I've added in my original post. You are right about the way I work with the model, but you can see I already pass the `Model[i]` in the @Html.Partial and still I get null in my controller. Why do you think this happen?

Comment: @Leron You haven't actually got any fields that hold any data to be sent back to the server? You only have `DisplayFor`, that doesn't get posted. Try adding a `HiddenFor` and see if there's any difference.

Comment: In fact I have 3 fields :) But have to leave now. Gonna accept your answer and look over it tomorrow and add some `HiddenFor` to get more information back. Thanks.